# Getting data from multiple-encoded file

Tags: java, encoding

I'm writing parser for Thunderbird mails.

**Input:**
I've got a file with load of emails (main part written in ANSI - WINDOWS 1250, but the content is in utf-8 or iso-8859-2, it is written in mail's Content-Type markup).

**Output:**
Collection of messages content (body).

So that's what I do:

1. Read whole file into a byte[] variable. (still ANSI)
2. Convert it to String. (utf-16 but bytes as from ANSI) - I need to convert to String now, because i need to get to the next point (divide bunch of messages -> sole message)
3. Divide bunch of messages into a separate message and add every message into Collection (utf-16).
4. Check Content-Type of a message.
5. Using JavaMail API i use `mail.getContent`(utf-16 I guess, but I'm not sure of encoding inside).
6. This is my problem: I have a String in UTF-16 i guess, and it's content is e.g. iso-8859-2, so what should I do now?

I was using Charset, and new String(byte[],String (charset name) ), but none of my tries made it.

My try:

1. Convert final String from UTF-16 -> UTF-8 (cause it's the same amount of bytes as in 8859-2)
2. Get bytes from utf-8 and encode it as ANSI
3. Decode ANSI to utf-8
4. Encode utf-8 to ISO-8859-2 (or leave it, if it already has been utf-8)
5. Decode from ISO-8859-2.
   But it's not giving me any good results.

how may I deal with it? Too many decodings for me, and I feel dizzy.

Input (this was hold as a cp1250 file, but i converted it to utf-8, ):

```
  From - Thu Dec 08 15:06:14 2011
(some mail header stuff....)
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-2"
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="600"><tbody><tr><th class="ffield2"><span class="cald-word">clich&eacute;d</span> </th><td class="field1"><br>
banal; <b>banalny<b>
<br>
She made a <span class="cald-word">clich&eacute;d remark about the importance of friendship.</span>
<br>
<b>Wygԯsiԡ jakѶ banalnѠuwagꡯ wadze przyjaݮi . <br>
<b>
<b> <b><br>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
From - Thu Dec 08 15:42:09 2011
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
(some mail header stuff....)
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="600"><tbody><tr><th class="ffield2">nosiness</th><td class="field1"><br>
<br>
interest in somebody else's business; <b>wścibstwo<b>
<br>
Nosiness is something I can't stand, so stop asking such questions.
<br>
<b>Nie znoszę wścibstwa, więc przestań zadawać takie pytania. <b><b> <br>
<b>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: I can't speak for Java, but if you have a "string in UTF-16 whose content is ISO-88859-2", you have already screwed up. You need to keep the raw bytes around (in a `byte[]` I guess for Java) until you know what encoding those bytes represent, then convert them to a native string using that encoding. Something along the lines of `String str = bytes.toStringUsingEncoding('ISO-88859-2')` (again, don't know the Java way to do this exactly).

Comment: I read, that every character from ISO has a representation in Unicode, so I shouldn't be losing any character in this case. Unfortunately, I have in a file written a mails headers in UTF-8, and content in either utf or iso, and I need encipher headers from byte[] to get to know the encoding.
Nevertheless, "screwed up" is an appropriate word.

Comment: The problem is that when something is represented as a *string* in Java, Java has already parsed the bytes into *characters*. To do so it needs to *decode* the bytes according to their encoding. UTF-16 is a superset of all other possible encodings, so you won't lose any characters, but you're screwing up which characters you're storing because you're decoding them without knowing their encoding.

Comment: Perhaps a sample of what your input is would help. Do you have *one mixed encoding file*, i.e. one text file that contains text is several different encodings? That already sounds quite foobar'd if so.

Comment: I posted an input sample. I converted my input file to utf-8, so I don't need to struggle with ANSI, now I only need to convert from utf-8 (or 16) to ISO, which sounds much easier.
About input: file is an utf-8 file that consists of some ISO fragments.

Comment: Then it very much looks like your encoding is already screwed up. Maybe you should start with [What every programmer needs to know about encodings](http://kunststube.net/encoding).

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieving unicode text from notepad which is saved as ANSI text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750474/retrieving-unicode-text-from-notepad-which-is-saved-as-ansi-text-file)