# retrieving unicode text from notepad which is saved as ANSI text file

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, ascii, notepad

Yesterday I wrote some text in a notepad file which was full of Unicode characters and saved the file as ANSI. Notepad gave me some warning, which i clicked OK without reading it fully and closed notepad.

Today when I again opened the same text in notepad, I am seeing notepad full of ??? signs. I now understand that this happened because I saved Unicode data as ANSI text. Is there a way to retrieve this text back? May be using some hex-editor or so?

Comment: This is a good question but off-topic here (would fit into SuperUser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Certain characters cannot be encoded in certain encodings. "風" cannot be encoded at all in ISO-8859 or any other single-byte encoding, for example. Each ANSI encoding also can only encode a certain subset of all possible characters. It is simply not possible to store characters not defined in a particular ANSI encoding in that encoding, they're simply not defined there.

So, they're gone. You better pull out a backup.

Comment: The warning from Notepad is somewhat misleading, as it warns about disappearing characters. Instead, Notepad replaces them by U+003F QUESTION MARK characters. Either way, there is indeed no way to get them back from the file (but you can see where they were, except that you cannot distinguish such a “?” from a question mark that was in the file from the beginning).

Comment: Well, replacing a valid character with "?" is just as well as "disappearing" IMO. ;)